# how to show two models data in one template - django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

***I need to get two models data in one template. If I loop without union this two models in one tuple or list, I get too much looped info as you know, so I need your help there.***

**This is what I tried, but it did not work...**

```
 @login_required
    def my_hotels(request):
        hotels_info = AddHotelStep1.objects.all()
        hotels_info_2 = AddHotelStep2.objects.all()
        info = dict()
        info['hotels_info'] = hotels_info
        info['hotels_info_2'] = hotels_info_2
        context = {'info':info,}
        return render(request, 'myhotels.html', context)
```

**This is my template:**

```
    {% for hotel in info %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated and hotel.customer == user %}
            {{hotel.hotel_name}}
            {% with ''|center:hotel.star as range %}
                {% for i in range %}
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
            {{hotel.hotel_type}}
            {{hotel.short_description}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**This is my models:**

```
class AddHotelStep1(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    long_description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    HOTEL_STAR = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5')
    )
    star = models.TextField(max_length=1, default=5, choices=HOTEL_STAR, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', default="images/default.jpg", blank=True)
    
class AddHotelStep2(models.Model):
    hotel_name_2 = models.ForeignKey(AddHotelStep1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    HOTEL_TYPE = (
        ('Single', 'Single'),
        ('Double', 'Double'),
    )
    hotel_type = models.TextField(max_length=10, choices=HOTEL_TYPE)
```

***I would get any advice to solve it.***

Comment: Please do not make models like `AddHotel`, a model should not be tailored towards a use-case: it should be tailored to how to represent data in a use-case unaware context.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with:

```
@login_required
def my_hotels(request):
    hotels_info = AddHotelStep1.objects.all()
    hotels_info_2 = AddHotelStep2.objects.all()
    info = zip(hotels_info, hotels_info_2)
    context = {'info':info,}
    return render(request, 'myhotels.html', context)




{% for hotel, hotel2 in info %}
      {% if user.is_authenticated and hotel.customer == user %}
            {{hotel.hotel_name}}
            {% with ''|center:hotel.star as range %}
                {% for i in range %}
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
            {{hotel2.hotel_type}}
            {{hotel.short_description}}
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute `hotel_name_2` in your templates. I see you are also not looping through the hotels queryset but the info dict. So the solution to your problem may be:

1. loop through `info.hotels_info`
2. access attribute `hotel.hotel_name_2`

```
    {% for hotel in info.hotels_info %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated and hotel.customer == user %}
            {{ hotel.hotel_name }}
            {% with ''|center:hotel.star as range %}
                {% for i in range %}
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
            {{ hotel.hotel_name_2.hotel_type }}
            {{ hotel.short_description }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I loop info.hotels_info how can I get access in hotels_info_2 ? It is not working...